# Create CGImage from HEIF file

Tags: macos, core-graphics, cgimage, heif

This is how I load a JPEG or PNG file into a **CGImage**:

```objectivec
imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename( [imgFilepath UTF8String] );

if( [[imgFilepath pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"png"] )
{
    image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
}
else if( [[imgFilepath pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"jpg"] || [[imgFilepath pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"jpeg"] )
{
    image = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
}
```

Unfortunaltey the is not a `CGImageCreateWith`... variant for **HEIF**

How do I create a **CGImage** from a HEIF encoded image file?

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought

```objectivec
imageSrc = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL( (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgFilepath], nil );
image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex( imageSrc, 0, nil );
```